# Junit, How to cover the callback code using Junit?

Tags: java, junit, callback

I have to write a test case to cover a method which has a callback as one of the parameters. It looks something like the snippet below.

```
JAXBElement<MyCustomObject> obj = null;

try {
    obj = (JAXBElement<MyCustomObject>) template.marshall("some string", new SoapActionCallback("some string") {
        public void doWithMessage(MyMessageClass message) {
          // some logic 
});
}
```

How do cover the callback logic ?

I am not able to figure out how to cover the callback logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is the best pattern, but what I often do is to use [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to work with these kind of callbacks.

```
@Test
public void testMethod() throws Exception {
    JAXBElement<MyCustomObject> obj = null;

    //Instantiate a future before the callback
    final CompletableFuture<MyMessageClass> callbackFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

    try {
        obj = (JAXBElement<MyCustomObject>) template.marshall("some string", new     SoapActionCallback("some string") {
        public void doWithMessage(MyMessageClass message) {
          //Complete the future within the callback
          callbackFuture.complete(message);
        });
    }

   //Wait until the future has completed in your callback and do the verification afterwards
   MyMessageClass message = callbackFuture.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   assertEquals("your verification", message.toString());

}
```